# Office365 - removing multiple licenses at the same time doesn't work as expected

Tags: powershell, office365

I am working on a script which connects O365 environment and removes the licenses.

Now I need to remove multiple licenses that are not relevant to user anymore. And the list of such type of licenses will be present in a string variable.

If I am knowing the name of the licenses before hand this is how the command will look :

```
Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName "ID_TestB@lic.com" -RemoveLicenses "liconline:DESKLESSPACK","liconline:OFFICESUBSCRIPTION";
```

Above command will the two remove licenses namely desklesspack and officesubscription for the uses ID_TestB@lic.com (**notice the double quotes in each of the license name**)

But this is not how things will be as I want to make it dynamic wherein I will be passing the licenses directly to a variable

So now if I capture these licenses in a variable let's say $license, where $license is

```
$license="`"liconline:DESKLESSPACK`",`"liconline:OFFICESUBSCRIPTION`""
```

backticks are escape character in powershell so I am escaping the double quotes which should be part of the text by a backtick

Now if I use this

```
Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName "ID_TestB@lic.com" -RemoveLicenses $license;
```

this throws me an error

> Set-MsolUserLicense : Unable to assign this license because it is
>   invalid. Use the Get-MsolAccountSku cmdlet to retrieve a list of valid
>   licenses.

I also tried doing it this way :

```
$license1 = "liconline:DESKLESSPACK";
$license2 = "liconline:OFFICESUBSCRIPTION";
Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName "ID_TestB@licent.com" -RemoveLicenses $license1, $license2;
```

which worked.

again this is not a dynamic approach as it might happen there are more than two licenses.

If anyone has any idea by which this can work please help. ***Also I don't want to split the string and iterate via a for loop***

Comment: The double quotes are NOT part of the license names. Simply create a string array `$license = "licentonline:DESKLESSPACK", "licentonline:OFFICESUBSCRIPTION"` to use for the `-RemoveLicenses` parameter. See [Set-MsolUserLicense](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/set-msoluserlicense?view=azureadps-1.0#parameters). The  `RemoveLicenses` wants a string array `[string[]]`. Also, in Powershell you do not need to end each line with a semi-colon.

Comment: P.S. you made a typo is it `licentonline` or `liconline`?

Comment: show the result of `Get-MsolAccountSku`

Comment: @Theo Thanks a lot man!!! works like a charm. I really misinterpreted it. Yup I know, my bad. I am used to non scripting languages like Java,C++ and can't put behind that habit somehow.

Also actually that isn't a typo. Just an ignorance :p. Actually this issue is being faced in my work related script and I can't reveal the details so I was using dummy enterprise names didn't care enough to check both the times I used same name or not while describing the problem 

Anyways thank you very much :)

Comment: @Avshalom

Thanks but Theo helped to fix the issue. I was passing a string, instead it should have been a string array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was doing it the wrong way.

While using the -RemoveLicenses switch Powershell expects a string array not a string, I interpreted comma separated double quotes as a string that was causing the problem.

So solution to this would be :

```
$license="licentonline:DESKLESSPACK","licentonline:OFFICESUBSCRIPTION"
#powershell will automatically convert above string to an array
Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName "ID_TestB@licent.com" -RemoveLicenses $license;
```